# JQuery Toggle & Image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a + icon and a - icon. When someone clicks the + icon a box appears and the icon changes to a - icon. If they click again the box disappears and the icon changes to a + icon.

Here is the code I tried but its not working...

```
$("#box").toggle(function(e){
        $("#icon").attr ("src","/images/icon_expand.png")
    },
    function(e) { 
        $("#icon").attr("src","/images/icon_retract.png")
    }
);
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Provide more info please. What is #icon, what do you mean by "not working", etc ...

Comment: Hi #icon is the image that changes to + or -. #box is the box that appears and disappears via the JQuery toggle function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function attaches `click` handlers to the element, not event handlers for then an element is toggled visible, it should be attached to `#icon`, like this:

```
$("#icon").toggle(function(){
  $("#box").hide();
  this.src = "/images/icon_expand.png";
}, function() { 
  $("#box").show();
  this.src = "/images/icon_retract.png";
});
```

Comment: @Nick Craver : but this won't make the _box_ toggle.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not the one who downvoted ;) even if it would be deserved here :p

Comment: @Chouchenos - I didn't read the question like that, I read it as something *else* was making the box toggle and this was an attempt to rig an event handler to that...none the less I've added the complete example above to eliminate any confusion.

Comment: Interesting. Is this an undocumented feature? I cannot find it at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: @Frank - There is another `.toggle()` overload (like `.load()` for loading content vs the load event), the other is here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me too Nick!

Comment: @AZKyleP - please take a look at the code above, there's no need for `.attr()` when it's not needed, use basic DOM properties when they're immediately available and *much* cheaper.

Comment: I'm going to try your code now Nick. The code Jan posted has an issue.

Comment: @AZKyleP - are you running this inside a `document.ready` handler...or is the `#icon` element being added later somehow (e.g. AJAX)?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> function Keywords(){ $("#icon").toggle(function(){ $("#box").hide(); this.src = "/images/icon_expand.png"; }, function() { $("#box").show(); this.src = "/images/icon_retract.png"; }); } </script> </head> <body> <table> <tr><td><img src=/images/icon_expand.png id=icon onClick=Keywords();></td></tr> <tr id=box style=display:none;><td><div id=keywords>$keys</div></td></tr> </table>

Comment: Thats how I'm calling it. Sorry for some reason stackoverflow removed all my line breaks.

Comment: @AZKyleP - That's not how this was intended to be used, there's no inline script at all...you should attach it like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/kQBHs/ (note the handlers are reversed as well, since it starts hidden).

Comment: Gotcha! Works perfectly! Sorry I'm new to JQuery/JavaScript. Thank you for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

[$.togle ()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) toggles the visibility of the matched element(s). So you are using it completely wrong.

You'll have to do something like this:

```
$( '#icon' ).click ( function () {
    var $this = $( this );
    var $box = $( '#box' );

    $box.toggle ();

    if ( $box.is ( ':visible' ) === true ) {
        $this.attr ( "src", "/images/icon_retract.png" );
    } else {
        $this.attr ( "src", "/images/icon_expand.png" );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Oops! Your code works but its a little buggy. First click expand works but you need to click it twice to get it to retract.

Answer (score 0):

i think, there will be a correction in Nick code and then it will work fine.
you have to first show the box and on second click you have to hide it, if is it so,
then try this

> $("#icon").toggle(function(){
>        **$("#box").show();**
>     this.src = "/images/icon_expand.png";
>   }, function() {
>    **$("#box").hide();**
>          this.src = "/images/icon_retract.png";
>   });